# Pip installed, but command not found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip

I checked a few posts with similar wording in the question, and tried out the offered solutions, but I have not been able to fix the problem.
My computer says pip is installed, but it does not recognize the command.
When I try to use 'sudo' to install it, it won't let me, responding that it is already installed, as shown in the attached photo.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to me too. Try:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

I hope it helps.